# How can select row in hypertable

Tags: select, row, hypertable

First I had created one table

```
    CREATE TABLE hypertable (a,b);
after I add 4 row into that:
    INSERT INTO hypertable VALUES ('2008-06-28 01:00:00', 'a', 'a11'),('2008-06-28 01:00:00', 'b', 'b11');
    INSERT INTO hypertable VALUES ('2008-06-28 01:00:00', 'a', 'a12'),('2008-06-28 01:00:00', 'b', 'b12');
    INSERT INTO hypertable VALUES ('2008-06-28 01:00:00', 'a', 'a13'),('2008-06-28 01:00:00', 'b', 'b13');
    INSERT INTO hypertable VALUES ('2008-06-28 01:00:00', 'a', 'a14'),('2008-06-28 01:00:00', 'b', 'b14');
```

Last I select all in table it will show like this:

```
hypertable> select * from hypertable;
2008-06-28 01:00:00     a       a14
2008-06-28 01:00:00     a       a13
2008-06-28 01:00:00     a       a12
2008-06-28 01:00:00     b       b14
2008-06-28 01:00:00     b       b13
2008-06-28 01:00:00     b       b12
hypertable>
```

it only show in one line for one value it can't show all value of one row in a table:( how can I select in one row it will be show all value of that row
in this case I add 4 row but it show 8 line

Answer (score 0):

Your time stamp is exactly same for all four entries you are adding for each key, `'2008-06-28 01:00:00'`.

So it will only save the last value added `2008-06-28 01:00:00     a       a14`.

In hypertable time stamp must be unique, you can time stamp as small as in nano seconds.